# Usage of か after a clause?

Tags: particles, syntax, particle-か

Here's a sentence I found:

> デパートはどこにあるか、知っていますか？
>   Do you know where the department store is?

What's the purpose of the か particle in 「どこにあるか」? Under what circumstances do I use it?

I'm fairly sure it's not the か that's normally used to form questions, like the second か in that sentence, nor is it the か that means “or.”

Answer (score 28):

These are sometimes called **embedded questions**, but if you look them up you'll find a variety of terminology in use, including "embedded interrogative content clauses" and "indirect questions".

---

I think the か in embedded questions is more or less the same か used to form regular questions.  But there are a couple differences:

- In an embedded question, it's okay to have だ before か:

  > *1.*　[　誰**だか**　]　分からない　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　←　　*okay*
- In an embedded question, か generally can't be omitted:

  > *2.*　デパートは　[　どこにある**か**　]　知っていますか？　　←　　**か** *can't be omitted*

Another difference is that embedded interrogatives can function like nouns (for examples, see Satoshi Tomioka's paper [*Japanese Embedded Questions are Nominal*](http://udel.edu/~stomioka/papers/tomioka_QVE.pdf), especially pages 8 and 9).  In fact, we might want to say as a matter of theory that the か-phrase is the direct object of 知る:

```
　 　 3a.　[　どこにあるか　]-を　知らない  
　 　 3b.　[　どこにあるか　] 　　知らない
```

We might choose to say that sentence 3b is derived from sentence 3a by omitting を.  But in practice, it's usually omitted, particularly in conversation, and sometimes inserting を is strange, so I'm not sure if this is the right approach.  ([See our discussion in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18356802#18356802))

---

We have embedded questions in English, too:

> *4a.* **What** are you talking about?
>   　　 *4b.* I don't know [ **what** you're talking about ].

In *4a* we have a basic question, and in *4b* we have the embedded question corresponding to *4a*.  Likewise, in Japanese, we can write:

> *5a.* **何**を言っているのか？
>   　　 *5b.* [　**何**を言っているのか　]　分からない。

As you can see, embedded questions straightforwardly correspond to main clause questions, although in each language there are small differences in syntax.

Comment: Does this か not correspond to an [indirect question](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/indirect_questions.htm)? Maybe I'm missing something big here.

Comment: @3to5businessdays Yes, some people call interrogative content clauses "indirect questions" or "embedded questions" etc.  (I should clean this answer up...)

Comment: How about a sentence like 調査でどんな証拠が見つかるかに応じて起訴を推すかを決めよう。
The first question refers more to a yet unknown circumstance than a question as such. The か particle seems to indicate more doubt than inquisition.

Comment: @EspenNielsen I think "embedded interrogative content clause" would probably be the most accurate term.  I was trying not to hit people over the head with terminology, so I went with a simpler term that people sometimes use.

Answer (score 4):

Think of this か as a **の** that is nominalizing a question.

デパートはどこにあるか、知{し}っていますか？

Do you know where is the department store?

In **spoken casual** conversation I've heard native speakers drop the か and communicate just as effectively, but I would recommend always using か.

Comment: I'm not sure か can be dropped in this case. It sounds weird to me, and googling for "どこにある、知" only yields 9 results, of which just two are grammatically similar to this case: 「…それは私の中心がどこにある知られていないので…」 and 「…それは私の中心地がどこにある知られていないため…」 By comparison, "どこにあるか、知" has 12400 results, "どこにあるのか、知" has 6330.

Comment: You may be able to communicate even if you drop the か, but it is **not grammatical** to do so as far as I can tell (this may not be true in some particular dialect or another, I suppose...). The best I can think of is that if you split it into two sentences with rising intonation at the end of the first (デパートはどこにある↗ [pause] 知っていますか？） then it is, if not entirely natural, at least more or less grammatical.

Comment: Definitely not acceptable in written language, but just fine in spoken conversation.