# Translating “どうして〜のか忘れがちになる”

Tags: grammar, translation

I’m having major trouble understanding and translating these example sentences.

> 試験や勉強で忙しくなると、どうして勉強しているのか忘れがちになる。でも勉強は自分のためにしているということを忘れないでほしい。

My translation: When you become busy with exams and your studies, why do you tend to forget your studying? But in order to study for yourself I don’t want you to forget?

My translations don’t make much sense but that’s the trouble I’m having. I understand all the vocab and grammar used but I just can’t translate that into intelligible English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it this say:

> {どうして勉強しているのか(を)}忘れがちになる。

どうして勉強しているか is the object of 忘れ(る).

> 「勉強は自分のためにしている」**と**いうことを忘れないでほしい。

The と is the quotative particle.

Comment: All I needed was those two hints (cheers) and I was able to come up with a better translation on my own: 

"When you become busy with exams and study you tend to forget why you’re studying (in the first place). I don’t want you to forget that you’re studying for yourself."

I somehow missed the quotative という but I'm not sure I would have figured out the use of か as an embedded question described more in bob's answer.

Comment: 訳は良いと思います！(^^)v

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you're doing is misunderstanding the [usage of "embedded" questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/usage-of-%E3%81%8B-after-a-clause/13038#13038).

My translation:

> When you get busy with exams and your studies it can be easy to forget why you're even studying, but I want you to remember that you're studying for your own benefit.