# What is the use of か in 売り始めるか〜

Tags: particles, particle-か, interrogatives, subordinate-clauses

I was reading an article and I came across this sentence:

> 車の会社がいつごろこのような自動運転の車を売り始める**か**予想しました

What exactly does the か in this sentence/what is the meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This か is the same as the particle we see all the time at the end of an interrogative sentence. It's also used in a noun clause like so:

> - いつ車を売りますか? When do they sell the cars?
>     いつ車を売るか (noun clause) when they sell the cars
> - 今日は日曜日ですか? Is it Sunday today?
>     今日は日曜日か (noun clause) whether it is Sunday today

Therefore, "車の会社がいつごろこのような自動運転の車を売り始めるか" is a long noun clause which means "when the automobile companies begin to sell those self-driving cars."

**EDIT**:
I found a related question with an extensive answer:
[Usage of か after a clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010)