# What about these words without transitive/intransitive mark?

Tags: grammar

For example this one: 
http://jisho.org/search/yorokobu

It appeared in this sentence:

> 「両親{りょうしん}が生{い}きていたら、孫{まご}の誕生{たんじょう}をとても喜{よろこ}んだだろう。」

"If my parents had still lived, I think they would have been very pleased by the birth of their grandchild."

Are these verbs suitable for both transitive and intransitive use?
And do they "prefer" certain particles, or is that mostly determined by context?
In this particular case, I'm a bit confused by the use of を since it is in most cases reserved for the direct object, and at least in my attempt at translation, this isn't reflected at all...^^

Comment: To back up @naruto's brilliant answer, here's what 明鏡国語辞典 says: 「よろこぶ【喜ぶ（慶ぶ・悦ぶ・歓ぶ）】〘 **他**五〙❶...『実験の成功**を**心からよろこぶ』... (語法)『合格の知らせ**に**小躍りしてよろこぶ』など**自動詞としても使う** 。～ヲが単に〈喜びの対象〉を表すのに対し、～ニは、～を知って喜びを感じる意で、 **喜びの原因**に重きを置いた表現となる。」

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44523/can-verbs-be-both-transitive-and-intransitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, 喜ぶ has both transitive and intransitive usages. The following sentences are both grammatical and mean the same thing.

> - 彼は孫の誕生**に**喜んだ。
> - 彼は孫の誕生**を**喜んだ。

Here, に is the case particle which can denote a reason/cause (e.g., ～に戸惑う, ～に驚く, ～に悲しむ).

I feel the transitive usage (～を喜ぶ) is more common, but ～に戸惑う is not uncommon at all. Here the first five examples of ～に喜ぶ I found on BCCWJ. These are safely interchangeable with ～を喜ぶ.

> - 実験の成功**に**喜ぶ圭介の腕に思いがけず抱きしめられ...
> - 水の出た井戸**に**喜ぶ、アフガンの子どもたち
> - 市内に転入した方へあさか舞をプレゼントし、新米のプレゼント**に**喜ぶ姿が見られました。 (あさか舞 is a brand name of rice)
> - スケートに誘われ、久しぶりのデート**に**喜ぶ…のも束の間、...
> - 写真は開催地決定の報**に**喜ぶ北京の学生たち。

Comment: Thanks! about your examples:
Third example: "I gave あさか舞 as a present to people who just moved into their house in the city, and a figure enjoying the present of new rice was seen/could be seen."
First, 見られました　should be passive right? potential is 見える　if I remember correctly. 
Second: Is this passive construction a way to express that someone is delighted by something? Especially the very abstract, impersonal word choice of "figure" or "picture" ( 姿 ) makes me wonder wether I interpreted this correctly.

Comment: Your fourth example: 
Maybe its because some context was lost in this sentence, but I have problems coordinating the temporal information given in this part: 久しぶりのデートに喜ぶ…のも束の間
=> I am invited to skating and since a long time it will be a brief moment I enjoy a date (=I am delighted by a date). 

I don't really know how to make 久しぶり an attribute to デート. To be honest, I also don't know what to make of the particles in のも 束の間, so I just translated it in a way that made senst to me.

Answer (score -1):

> 両親が生きていたら、孫の誕生をとても喜んだだろう。
> ↓
> 両親が生きていたら、(**両親は**) 孫の誕生をとても喜んだだろう。
> ↓
> 両親が生きていたら、（両親は）孫の誕生をとても喜んだと**私は思う**。
> ↓
> 私は「両親が生きていたら彼らが孫の誕生をとても喜んだ」と思う。

もとの文の基本は次のように簡単な文章になります。

> 彼らが/は孫の誕生**を**喜ぶ

「喜ぶ」は他動詞（transitive verb）であり、「孫の誕生」が目的語（object）です。

とても簡単な構文です。

Please think in Japanese, not in other languages.

---

## 回答の追加（１）「喜ぶ」の品詞

質問者の例文が、「～を喜ぶ」でしたので、当然「喜ぶ」を他動詞だとして回答しました。
その後、narutoさんの回答やChocolateさんのコメントで紹介する説明を見て、そういう用法もあるのだと、改めて知りました。

しかし、narutoさんの説明にあった「彼は孫の誕生に喜んだ。」と「彼は孫の誕生を喜んだ。」がどちらも同じ意味（たぶん日本語として大丈夫と言う意味）であるとの説明を見て、少し疑問を感じました。「彼は孫の誕生に喜んだ。」は、意味は分かるがどうも変な日本語だなあとの印象が拭えません。

更に疑問を持ったものは、narutoさんが BCCWJ で見つけてきた「～に喜ぶ」の用例です。
「に」と「を」を置き換えて何度も読んでみました。
日本語としてどれも意味は分かりますが、何だか日本語としてみたとき違和感があります。
以下の文に付けた〇、△、×の印はいずれも私の直観です。〇は違和感なし。×は違和感大です。普通の人が感じる以上に１ランクずつ*厳しめに見ている*とご理解ください。

- × 実験の成功に喜ぶ圭介の腕に思いがけず抱きしめられ...
- △ 実験の成功を喜ぶ圭介の腕に思いがけず抱きしめられ...
- × 水の出た井戸に喜ぶ、アフガンの子どもたち
- × 水の出た井戸を喜ぶ、アフガンの子どもたち
- × 新米のプレゼントに喜ぶ姿が見られました。
- △ 新米のプレゼントを喜ぶ姿が見られました。
- × スケートに誘われ、久しぶりのデートに喜ぶ…のも束の間、...
- △ スケートに誘われ、久しぶりのデートを喜ぶ…のも束の間、...
- × 写真は開催地決定の報に喜ぶ北京の学生たち。
- × 写真は開催地決定の報を喜ぶ北京の学生たち。

「～に喜ぶ」と「～を喜ぶ」の使い分け以上に、「～を喜ぶ」という文でも不自然な日本語だと感じるものがあるのには正直に驚きました。

そこで、「彼は孫の誕生に喜んだ。」と「彼は孫の誕生を喜んだ。」とで実験してみました。

- × 彼は孫の誕生に喜んだ。
- △ 彼は孫の誕生を喜んだ。
- × 彼は誕生した孫に喜んだ。
- △～× 彼は誕生した孫を喜んだ。

改めて居心地の良いと感じる日本語に対する私の許容度は低いとは思いますが、上記の実験から判断すると、どうも「～に喜ぶ/～を喜ぶ」の前の **名詞の種類（性質）** によって居心地の良さが変わることが何となく分かってきました。この件に関しましては、narutoさんが引用した５つの例文と合わせて、どうすれば居心地の良い日本語に変身できるかも現在見つけつつあります。まとまったら、また、紹介したいと思います。

さて、「喜ぶ」が自動詞か他動詞かの本題に戻ります。
何気なく調べておりましたところ、日本語の他動詞、自動詞の判定が相当にいい加減であるという情報を見つけました。

日本語教師と名乗る方の文で、[自動詞・他動詞](http://niwasaburoo.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/08/30/174017)、 [自動詞・他動詞（２）](http://niwasaburoo.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/09/14/130122)、 [自動詞・他動詞（３）](http://niwasaburoo.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/09/21/212716)にあります。

かいつまんで言いますと、「～を喜ぶ」「～に喜ぶ」の他動詞/自動詞の判断も辞書（辞書編集者？）によって違うようです。「～を喜ぶ」自体を自動詞にしている辞書もあります。これには私も初耳で、奥が深いというか何なのでしょうかと言う感想です。ぜひご覧ください。

今後日本語の拠り所をどこに置くのかなと思うと、偉そうに日本人面して回答しておれないところです。