# Help to understand a sentence: どのように and か

Tags: words, syntax

I am having trouble to understand this sentence. Why is どのように here? I looked it up on some dictionaries, but I couldn't get it. I have the same problem with か. Why are those words in the sentence below?

> 会社で**どのように**働く**か**しっかり考える学生が増えているようです。

Comment: It seems that the number of students, who seriously think of how to work in a company, is increasing. We call this as embedded question.

誰が僕のミルクを飲んでしまったか全然分からないんですよ。

Comment: My question was not about translation. Could you answer it?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We call 会社でどのように働くか as an embedded question (EQ).

会社でどのように働くか is an embedded question that becomes an object of the verb 考える and を is usually dropped.

- 会社でどのように働くか考える学生 means students who think of how to work in a company.
- 会社でどのように働くか考える学生が増えている means the number of students who think of how to work in a company is increasing.
- 会社でどのように働くか考える学生が増えているようだ means it seems that the number of students who think of how to work in a company is increasing.

Comment: を after か is usually omitted.