# "もを" is too unnatural, so use a comma instead of "も" in this list?

Tags: particle-を, particle-も

Can I re-write this sentence:

> このクレジットカードは国内、国外を問わず、いろいろな場所で使える。

as

> このクレジットカードは国内**も**国外**もを**問わず、使える。

A good reason to have replaced the first "も" with "、" is to avoid the unfortunate, (but grammatically correct?), "もを" string of particles?

Comment: What makes you think it's unfortunate but grammatically correct?

Comment: I'd thought that, in general, stringing 2 or 3 particles together makes understanding what modifies what more difficult. And "(noun)もを..."  sounded strange.  But the more I repeat saying naruto's answer in my head, the better it sounds. This site is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct sentence is:

> このクレジットカードは国内**か**国外**か**を問わず使える。

This か is the question marker and forms [an embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010).

This should be straightforward because, in English, you should say "regardless of whether it's A or B", not "regardless of both A and B".

Of course you can also say it without 問わず at all:

> このクレジットカードは国内**でも**国外**でも**使える。

But note that 国外でもを is ungrammatical because ～でも (="also in ～") is an adverbial phrase which never serves as an object marked with を.

Comment: Thanks. This one really confused me! While you were responding, I actually changed "でも" to just "も".  I should not have done that. sorry.