# What does どうかじゃない mean?

Tags: translation

I get that どうか alone means something along the lines of "please", but what happens when you add じゃない as a suffix?
I've seen this being used before but I can't quite place my finger on what it might mean.
The full sentence would be それでもやれるかどうかじゃない.

Comment: What was the preceding sentence?  Is there any other context you can add?

Comment: @snailboat The full thing should be それでも やれるか どうかじゃない, though I'm not sure if it's connected myself, as I interpreted それでも やれるか to be a separate sentence..?

Comment: @sanada I believe that part is quite important and you might want to edit it to include it in the main question.

Comment: The question is rather what does 'かどうか' mean? See the 'or not' bit in Aeon Akechi's answer, as well as (e.g.) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48492/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

それでもやれるかどうかじゃない = 'Even so, it's not about whether you can/are able to do it or not.'