# What is the meaning of なのか in this sentences? Is it a grammar pattern?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words, learning, use-and-frequency

私が家でよく作るのは、生姜焼きや唐揚げ、鍋料理などです。どれも、とても簡単ですよ！どんな料理*なのか*を、少し説明しますね。

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57145/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69791/9831 ... or maybe this: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18994/9831

Answer (score 2):

In a sense, it's a "pattern", but it's something you can analyze logically. Let's do so step by step:

- (こんな)料理だ。
  It is (such-and-such) a cuisine.
- どんな料理か？
  <sup>(converted to a question using どんな)</sup>
  What (kind of) cuisine is it?
- どんな料理なのか？
  <sup>(with [explanatory-*no*](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/question-markers/)  for seeking clarification)</sup>
  What (kind of) cuisine is it?
- どんな料理なのか
  <sup>(as a noun clause, aka [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010))</sup>
  what (kind of) cuisine it is
- どんな料理なのかを、少し説明しますね。
  <sup>(the embedded question is used as the object of 説明する)</sup>
  I'll briefly explain **what (kind of) cuisine it is**.