# Question about the particular use of 'か'

Tags: grammar, particle-か, embedded-question

1. 今日**か**あした来てください。 (Please, come today or tomorrow)
2. 行く**か**行かない**か**、わかりません。(Go or not, I don't know)

I guess in these two cases 'か' means 'or', but why is there no 'か' after 'あした'. In example 2 there is a 'か' after '行かない'. It is because you are 'counting' the possibilities?
Need someone to clear that up for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, か in Sentence 1 and か in Sentence 2 are a bit different.

In Sentence 1, か is simply like "or". In this case, the second か is optional, but is *usually omitted* in modern Japanese.

> - リンゴかバナナ(か)を買う。
> - 私か佐藤さん(か)が行きます。

In Sentence 2, the two か's are forming two [embedded questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010) placed in parallel. In this case, か cannot be omitted (but the particle *after* the か is usually omitted, as described in the link).

> - 京都に行くか東京に行くか(を)決めましょう。
> - 生きるべきか死ぬべきか、それが問題だ。
>     To be or not to be, that is the question.