# What is the function of か between these two verbs?

Tags: particle-か

文章を読んで、何について書いているか考えてください. I think it means, read the sentence(s), and think about something to write. I don't understand why か is between 書いている instead of て-form.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/16104 probably related