# あるか確認 vs あるかを確認

Tags: usage, particle-を, embedded-question

I understand that both have almost the same meaning.
But I was pointed out.
Is this a preference issue, or is one prioritized?
i.e.

> 「リンゴマークがあるか確認します。」
> 「リンゴマークがあるかを確認します。」

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are grammatical, and it's a matter of preference to a certain degree. Generally speaking, が/を at the end of an embedded question before a verb is *usually* omitted unless you want to emphasize the embedded question.

> - リンゴマークがあるか(を)確認します。
> - 彼女がどこにいるか(が)分かりません。
> - ハートマークではなくリンゴマークがあるか**を**確認してください。
> - どうやるのかではなく、なぜやるのか**が**分かりません。
>     What I don't understand is *why* I do this, not *how* I do this.

Related: [Usage of か after a clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010)