# Particle omission in embedded questions

Tags: grammar, particles, questions, subordinate-clauses, embedded-question

Are there any rules or conventions on when to omit を (as in 1) or が (as in 2) when it comes to embedded questions?

1. この生物は何か教えてください。
2. どれがおいしいかまずいかさっぱりわかりません。

My gut feeling would be to generalize and say that the particles are mostly dropped in spoken /more casual language and kept in written/ more formal language, but honestly I feel like I've  seen them dropped relatively frequently even in written language so I am unsure... Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are talking about the particles here that would/could attach to the embedded questions (I.E. if you were to add them they would be adjacent to か) and not particles inside the embedded questions, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/69791/9831 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/9831 /

Comment: @Mindful yes! It seems that this was a duplicate question -- thank you Chocolate, for finding it !