# What is the meaning of 何に金を出しているのか分からせてくれる?

Tags: grammar, translation

I saw the following comment on a youtube video about a super-fast chef making some Japanese fried rice:

自分が何に金を出しているのか分からせてくれる技術ってあるよね

I'm learning Japanese by myself and, having only a shaky grasp of grammar, this sentence is too difficult for me to parse. My best guess is "How much money do I have to pay this guy for him to teach me this skill!" or something like it, but I'm sure this is wrong.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJdENiJVehE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 自分が何に金を出しているのか = for what I am paying money (see: [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010))
- 分からせてくれる = to make me understand
- 技術ってあるよね = there is (such-and-such) a skill, huh?

So the sentence is literally "There is a kind of skill that makes me understand what I am paying for". In other words this is a word of praise along the lines of "So this is why we have to pay money for the skills of chefs!"