# What is the meaning of どうかは here?

Tags: meaning, syntax, sentence

> 一般的にどうかは置いといて、私の場合は遠のいているかもですね(笑) 実際してないですし

So the person (female CEO) is asked about if marriage and birth hinder ones job, so she answer with this. Does どうかは置いといて mean "not to mind it"?

> 結婚も考えた時に完全に私のほうが収入も上がるし、役職も上がるしって思ったんですけど(笑)

Is she saying that she preferred  increasing the income and having a promotion over marriage

Context:

> 就活している中で、私は将来、結婚したいなっていう気持ちもあるんですが。そこのところはどうですか? 出世で遠のいてしまうイメージがあるので。
>
> 一般的にどうかは置いといて、私の場合は遠のいているかもですね(笑) 実際してないですし。これまでも打診を受けるたびに悩みました。初めてマネージャーになる時に、当時付き合っていた方がいて。結婚も考えた時に完全に私のほうが収入も上がるし、役職も上がるしって思ったんですけど(笑) でも、その役職を引き受けるって決めて。

Answer (score 2):

This どう "how; what about" refers to the same どう asked by the questioner (そこのところは**どう**ですか). 一般的にどうか forms an [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010).

> **一般的にどうか**は置いといて、...
>
> Putting aside **how it is in general**, (personally) ...

This は is a contrastive-wa ("general expectation" vs "personal experience"). Here, she is talking about her personal experience, but she does not want her experience to be generalized to the public.

> Is she saying that she preferred increasing the income and having a promotion over marriage

No. At least at this point, being a manager and being married were not mutually-exclusive options to her. Her concern here was "what happens if I chose **both**?", i.e., achieving a higher income and social status *than her husband*. This is still seen as atypical in Japan.