# How are the working in these sentence these two: かも　and or か and も

Tags: particles

I came across the paragraph in NHK:

ただし、国内では電気自動車のシェアは現状では1％に満たず、日本自動車工業会のまとめでは、去年国内で販売された乗用車のうちハイブリッド車が147万台余りだったのに対し、電気自動車は2万台余りにとどまっています。

ハイブリッド車などと比べ依然として割高な価格を引き下げることや充電スタンドなどのインフラを整備することが普及の条件ですが、車自体の性能や商品力を高められる**かも**メーカーにとっては課題となりそうです。

I have my doubts regarding the use of か ,も and in the second paragraph.

From I could figure out by breaking the sentence down, I think  か and も are working separately, but I might be wrong and it could be かも.

I broke the last sentence after the comma this way:

車自体の性能や商品力を高められる**かも**メーカーにとっては課題となり**そう**です。

car itself の performance や merchandise power を can be enhanced か(question) も(too) or かも(may) + maker にとっては issue + becomes + seems + is.

Comment: i believe かも here is an abbreviated form of かもしらない.

Comment: @A.Ellett I had no idea they would use かも abbreviated like this in a news article like this, specially when the article itself seems somewhat formal.

Answer (score 1):

This **か** is a question marker used to form an [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010). Everything before か forms a noun clause working as the subject of the sentence. **も** is just "also" which replaced the subject marker が. かも meaning "maybe" does not exist in this sentence.

- 車自体の性能や商品力を高められる**か**
  **Whether** they can improve the performance and appeal of the cars themselves
- も
  also
- メーカーにとっては課題となりそうです。
  will be a challenge for the manufacturers.

Comment: naruto: in your translation shouldn't it be "seems like it will be a challenge for the manufacturers" because of そう ?