# What is the meaning of this も?

Tags: translation, particle-も

I'm struggling to understand what the も is doing in the following sentence. I know that も can mean 'also' 'too' 'as well' and other things; depending on the context. I think the first も here means 'as well' but when I  try to translate,  my translation comes out as gibberish.

> [何処]{どこ}に行くのか知りたい気**も**するし、知りたくない気**も**する。

Context: (アイン is a girl)

> 立ち上がったアインだ、こちらを[一瞥]{いちべつ}する。[何処]{どこ}に行くのか知りたい気もするし、知りたくない気もする。だが、そんなことを迷っている時間はもらえなかった。アインは背を向け、部屋を出ていった。

My translation attempt:

> Ein does get up, glances my way. **Where will she go, I want to know her intention to do stuff as well as other things, also I don’t want to know her intention.** But, she would not give me time to puzzle over that sort of thing. Ein exits the room, her back oriented towards me.

Comment: Hints:  You see the opposites 知りたい and 知りたくない, right?  Also, 気 doesn't really mean "feeling" here.

Comment: @istrasci OH! the mo means 'A and B/A nor B' right?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do you understand the grammar of [embedded questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010)? This 何処に行くのか is a noun phrase that works as the object of 知る. どこに行くのか as an independent sentence means "Where will she go?", but どこに行くのか as a noun clause means "where she goes".

- どこに行くのか
  where she goes
- どこに行くのか知りたい
  I want to know where she goes
- どこに行くのか知りたい気がする
  I feel I want to know where she goes
- どこに行くのか知りたくない気がする
  I feel I don't want to know where she goes

も by itself is just "also" here. 気がする means "I feel", and 気もする means "I also feel".

> 何処に行くのか知りたい気もするし、知りたくない気もする。
>
> I feel I want to know where she will go, but I also feel I don't want to know (where she will go).

In other words, the speaker wants to know her destination, but he hates to understand her destination at the same time. This implies he somehow understands she is going to do something dirty or dangerous.