# Can someone help break down this sentence どこにあるか知っていますか?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, embedded-question

どこにあるか知っていますか?
I couldn't understand the usage of か after ある

Comment: Question subordinate clauses are connected to the main clause with か. Example: I don’t know **what he ate** would be **彼が何を食べたか**知らない

Comment: This construction is called an *embedded question*. See: [Usage of か after a clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13034/5010)

Answer (score 3):

どこにあるか is an embedded question:  *Where is it?*

知っていますか is the main sentence:  *Do you know?*

Putting these two together, you get

> Do you know where it is?