# Why 誰か and not 誰?

Tags: pronouns

I thought that 誰 meant 'who', such as in:

> 彼は誰ですか。'Who is he?'

Then, why in this sentence it is 誰か ('someone') which is used and not 誰?

> 彼女が誰か知っていますか。'Do you know who she is ?'

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure if it was you or someone else who analyzed it as 誰か rather than 誰+か. Does this answer your question? [Usage of か after a clause?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/usage-of-%e3%81%8b-after-a-clause)

Comment: It does, thanks. To be sure, here (https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%AA%B0%E3%81%8B) you have the definition ('someone') for 誰か. So it's two different things?

Comment: Yes, you would need to identify which it is by the overall grammar of the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, you can think of `誰か` as a contraction of `誰なのか` which stands for `who it is`.