# Meaning and usage of ～かとなれば

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, usage

I've found the grammar pattern ～かとなれば in this site:

https://www.vnjp.org/grammar/detail/293

https://www.vnjp.org/grammar/detail/294

and I would like to know **what does it mean as well as its usage**.

Unfortunately, I cannot understand Vietnamese, and when trying to google ～かとなれば, I coudn't find other websites explaining this grammar.

To the best of my knowledge (which is very limited), the closest thing would be ～となれば (when it comes to...), as explained, for example, here:

https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-to-naru-to-nareba-meaning/

but I'm not sure if ～かとなれば refers to the same or something similar. If it turned out to be the case, could I use for each of the next sets of patterns the 2 patterns interchangeably?

～と（も）なると / ～かと（も）なると

～と（も）なれば / ～かと（も）なれば

～と（も）なったら / ～かと（も）なったら

On the other hand, if it had a complete different meaning, apart from ～かとなれば, could I use as well the forms ～かとなると and ～かとなったら, or only ～かとなれば can be used?

Comment: I don't think かとなれば is common enough to be called a pattern. It's neither ungrammatical nor totally unnatural, but not comparable to those you mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section, it's not a pattern with a special meaning. It's a simple combination of [～となれば/～となると](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-to-naru-to-nareba-meaning/) and ～か. This か is a question marker that forms an [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010), which is a **noun**-clause.

Compare the following:

- 戦争となれば
  When it comes to war, ...
  If war starts, ...
- 戦争が終わるとなれば
  When it comes to the end of the war, ...
  If the war is to be ended, ...
- 戦争が終わる**か**となれば
  When it comes to whether or not the war will end, ...
  As for the possibility of ending this war, ...
  If you ask me if this war will end, ...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped a lot to understand ～かとなれば.